# How to recover corrupted database on Ubuntu: MySQL

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I am trying to recover a corrupt database using:

```
mysqlcheck -- all-databases
```

But it seems to be returning an error:

> - Checking for tables which need an upgrade, are corrupt or were not closed cleanly. root@ipadtest:/var/lib/mysql# ERROR 2002 (HY000):
>     Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>     '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)

How would I go about fixing the error so I can recover my database?

Edit1: I fired following two queries and see the error. May be this will help you to help me.

```
mysql start
```

> Warning: World-writable config file '/etc/mysql/my.cnf' is ignored
>       ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

> Warning: World-writable config file '/etc/mysql/my.cnf' is ignored
>       Enter password: 
>       ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)

Comment: Runs the mysql server?

Comment: you need to start the mysql daemon. mysql server needs to be running to be able to do the mysqlcheck, and if it's running maybe you forgot to add the -u username and -p flags

Comment: @Zelldon Mr. Superstar ... what do you mean by that?

Comment: @Erwin we have done that, but it didn't help...

Comment: if you run "ps aux | grep mysql" do you get something like  :    Ss   08:47   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe  ? or a line that contains --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock ?

Comment: @Erwin I am getting something like 17:41 0:1 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe

Comment: that means that that mysql server is up... usually the can't connect through socket error is because mysql server is dow.... try with sudo "find / -type s"  you're gonna get a big list of opened sockets... if mysqld is running, you should get in ubuntu something like "/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock" then check if in /var you have the symlink from /var/run/ to /run/ . if you don't find the mysqld.sock in the list then mysqld is starting but not opening the socket.

Comment: @Erwin .. Yes I could locate sqld.sock in the specified folder... but I'm getting later instructions.. Could you please elaborate? TIA

Comment: i'm assuming you are not root, if you are, remove "sudo" from the commands. You have /etc/mysql/my.cnf file with 777 or 666 permision, so you should apply "sudo chmod 644 /etc/mysql/my.cnf" and before you apply "sudo mysql start" run "sudo service mysql status" (ubuntu 14.10 or older) or "sudo systemctl status mysql.service" (ubuntu 15.04) and check if the service is running.  . after you change the permission to my.cnf  if the service is running go with "sudo systemctl restart mysql.service" (ubuntu 15.04) or "sudo service mysql restart"(ubuntu 14.10 or older)

Comment: @Erwin... I had not worked from last four days, Today i tried once again and it is working... how is started ... i don't know.  However, add your response on answer section... so i can accept it.

Comment: probably somebody restarted the server. anyway, i'm glad i could help with a little information. since i didn't helped you with the problem, i don't think i should be moving my suggestions to the answer section. you can "thumbs up" the comment if you want.